# Unity Android trouble writing output: Too many method references: 78573; max is 65536

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, dex

I'm making a mobile f2p game in Unity

After adding various SDKs..

**facebook** (to get peoples friends)

**gamesparks** (backend)

**firebase** (for sending push notifications)

**appodeal** (for ads, it was after adding this that I started having this error)

I cannot build to Android anymore getting this error

"Unable to convert classes into dex format"

"Too many method references: 76221; max is 65536"

[image]

I cant even paste the whole thing as it very annoyingly dissapears from the console a few seconds after it appears!! >:(

Theres a big thread about this here thats been going since May 2015... But there doesnt seem to be any clear solution.

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/too-many-method-references-max-is-65536.327064/

Is there a solution for this? Should I just give up? Ive already been struggling through the process to get each of these working and not conflicting with the others (with their various .jar files and androidmanifest.xml which I do not understand), it feels like I've now hit a brick wall